# Are there (restricted) instances when the deficiency and sum-of-proper-divisors functions are multiplicative?

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers, multiplicative-function

A function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is said to be *multiplicative* if
$$f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$$
whenever $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

It is known that the **sum-of-divisors function**
$$\sigma(x) = \sum_{d \mid x}{d}$$
is multiplicative.  It follows that the **abundancy index function**
$$I(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
is also multiplicative.

It is also known that the [**deficiency**](http://oeis.org/A033879)
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$$
and the [**sum-of-proper-divisors**](http://oeis.org/A001065)
$$s(x) = \sigma(x) - x$$
functions are, in general, not multiplicative.

My question is:

> Are there (restricted) instances when the deficiency and sum-of-proper-divisors functions are multiplicative?

**MOTIVATION FOR THE QUESTION**

When $yz$ is a [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) for $\gcd(y,z)=1$, then we know that
$$\sigma(yz) = \sigma(y)\sigma(z) = 2yz.$$

It turns out that we can also show that
$$D(y)D(z) = 2s(y)s(z),$$
if $yz$ is a perfect number with $\gcd(y,z)=1$.

(Of course, I do not hope to show that $D(yz)=D(y)D(z)$ if $yz$ is perfect and $\gcd(y,z)=1$, since $yz$ is perfect implies that $D(yz)=0$.  I just want to know if further *simplified* expressions may be obtained for either $D(y)D(z)$ or $s(y)s(z)$ (with $\gcd(y,z)=1$), whether or not $yz$ is perfect.)

Comment: At least, for $s(x)$ the answer is negative. For, $s(x)s(y)=s(xy)$ would be equivalent to $(\sigma(x)-x)(\sigma(y)-y)=\sigma(xy)-xy$, which by multiplicativity of $\sigma$ can be written as $y\sigma(x)+x\sigma(y)=2xy$, and hence is equivalent to $$\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}+\frac{\sigma(y)}y=2.$$ However, each of the two summands in the LHS exceeds $1$, except if $x=1$ and / or $y=1$.

Comment: @W-t-P:  Thank you for your comment.  Your argument appears to show that $s(x)s(y)=s(xy)$ for $\gcd(x,y)=1$ only holds when $x=1$ and $y=1$.  Of course, we know that $\gcd(1,y)=\gcd(x,1)=1$, $s(1)s(y)=s(1\cdot{y})=s(y)$, and $s(x)s(1)=s({x}\cdot{1})=s(x)$.  Note that $s(1)=\sigma(1)-1=1-1=0$.  So your logical connective should be an **AND** instead of an **OR**.

Comment: You are right, the argument shows that for $s(xy)=s(x)s(y)$ with $(x,y)=1$ to hold, it is necessary and sufficient that $x=y=1$. On the other hand, formally, "and / or"  can be replaced by just "or".

Comment: @W-t-P:  I invite you to write out your (first) comment as an actual answer, because I think it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these functions is multiplicative on any reasonable domain; in fact, for $x$ and $y$ coprime, we have $s(xy)=s(x)s(y)$ if and only if $x=y=1$, and $D(xy)=D(x)D(y)$ if and only if $\min\{x,y\}=1$.

Sufficiency is readily verified. For necessity, notice that $s(x)s(y)=s(xy)$ is equivalent to $(\sigma(x)−x)(\sigma(y)−y)=\sigma(xy)−xy$, which by multiplicativity of $\sigma$ is further equivalent to $yσ(x)+xσ(y)=2xy$, and eventually can be written as
  $$ \frac{\sigma(x)}x + \frac{\sigma(y)}y=2. $$
Taking into account that $\sigma(x)\ge x$ and $\sigma(y)\ge y$, with equalities if and only if $x=1$ and $y=1$, respectively, we conclude that $x=y=1$.

Similarly, for $x$ and $y$ coprime, the equality $D(xy)=D(x)D(y)$ can be equivalently rewritten as 
  $$ (\sigma(x)-x)(\sigma(y)-y)=0, $$
which implies $x=1$ or $y=1$ since if we had $x,y>1$, then both factors in the LHS were strictly positive.

Comment: Just double-checking:
$$D(xy) = D(x)D(y) \implies 2xy - \sigma(xy) = (2x-\sigma(x))(2y-\sigma(y)) = 4xy - 2x\sigma(y) - 2y\sigma(x) + \sigma(x)\sigma(y) \implies 2xy - 2x\sigma(y) - 2y\sigma(x) + 2\sigma(x)\sigma(y) = 2\bigg(x(y - \sigma(y)) - \sigma(x)(y - \sigma(y)\bigg) = 0$$
from which it (indeed) follows that
$$\bigg(\sigma(x)-x\bigg)\bigg(\sigma(y)-y\bigg)=0.$$

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @W-t-P!